# Returning a Card to hand & Charge

Tags: hearthstone

Regarding cards such as **Shadowstep** or **the Brewmasters** that return a minion on the battlefield to the owner's hand (usually friendly).

I know these are good for minions with battle-crys but I'm trying to ensure that most, if not all the cards in my decks have at least 2 strategies.

**Question**: Could you say, place a minion with **charge**, **attack**, **pick it** back **up** with one of the mentioned cards, **play it again** and **attack again**?

I'm aware it's not the most efficient/effective strategy but I could see some potential in it.

Comment: This is a viable strategy if you have Leeroy Jenkins in your hand.  Play him for 4, bounce him back with Panda for 2, play him again for 4 = 10 mana and 12 damage. Rogues can do it for 6.

Comment: This is a very effective strategy used in the Miracle Rogue decks.

Comment: It's also useful if you simply have a large near death creature that needs a heal.  An expensive one... but still gives you a little card advantage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could do that.  Returning a card to your hand does not change the wording on a card, so a minion with charge could attack twice in a round, at the cost of the mana required to summon that card twice.

However, as you've noted, it might not be the most efficient strategy, but if you absolutely need to do 2 damage and you have a Stonetusk Boar in your hand...

Comment: Cards with divine shield and charge are quite handy to play twice in a row though...

Comment: Shadowstep also reduces the minions summoning cost by 2, this can make double attacking slightly more viable. Especially when divine shield is involved.

Comment: @BlackVegetable are there any others than ArgentCommander? I find him to be on the costly side (6) 4/2

Comment: @Shelby115 I think you are correct.  Although as more cards are added, I'm sure something will pop up. However the Warrior can add charge to minions, so other divine shielded minions would benefit.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Sounds good except that warrior would require the Brewmasters to pull that off. i.e. (3)Brewmaster + (2)Charge + (X)Divine Minion Would be even less effective than other possibilities, such as Stampeding Kodo, Big Game Hunter, Defender of Argus, or even Mind Control Tech.

Comment: @Shelby115 Ah, I thought they had a minion that gave charge to all minions with 3 or less attack?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Indeed, I forgot about her as I don't run her often :P I just designed a deck that I believe has sufficient # of possible strategies per card. The worrisome part is a lot of them are using the Return, though I did try and make sure they aren't worthless without the return as I can have a max of 4 per warrior deck. I guess I'll see. Thanks to you and Jason for the comments/answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this works. When you play the card again it becomes a different minion. Since it hasn't attacked and it has charge, it can attack.

This strategy is actually used, if rarely, in competitive play by rogues with Shadowstep, Leeroy Jenkins and Cold Blood. It deals a total of 26 damage with 1x Leeroy, 2x Shadowstep & 2x Cold Blood.

Comment: Surely you mean 1x Leeroy.

Comment: @scenia Oops. Fixed that.